Outputting visuals from an RTX over a display plugged in to a HDBaseT GPU
I have a number of servers each with RTX GPUs, I want to use a card based solution to output visuals rendered on the RTX's over the HDBaseT card to displays far away. I can't just use the HDBaseT card because the graphics load is extremely high with multiple 4k 60Hz displays and high fidelity real time graphics. I know I can use T/R modules but that takes a lot of extra rack units and then you need loops of HDMI cables etc, not a clean solution for sure.
I know in the past it was possible to output over a different GPU using something like Virtu MVP, however that's quite an old solution. How can I achieve this?
To clarify; my visuals render on the RTX, my display plugs into the HDBaseT card. The chipset on these servers is W680 if it makes a difference!
